# Microsoft AX and Business Connector / Enterprise Portal / Application Integration Framework

Tags: axapta, x++, aif, enterprise-portal, business-connector

I've been working a while with a project aiming to integrate AX with the Web.

The company who delivered AX has chosen to use Business Connector (BC.net) directly on my side of the backend.

I've searched a bit, and for me it looks like we must use Application Integration Framework (AIF) / Enterprise portal (EP) - this due to as I understand that the BC is not made for multi-users like on the web, but must be implemented with a session-wrapper like EP - and also it must be run on an LAN and is not capable to connect via WAN.

Any comments about this?

--
-EDIT-
More info:

Oh, sorry - new to stackoverflow - didn't see that you had commented my question.

I'm doing this from scratch. 
The inital plan was to create a model, and send objects directly from AX via BC to my data layer, but since BC is not able to pass anything else then Axaptaobjects, we decided to serialise to XML, send as string with BC and then deserialize with my data layer.

Now, everything works, but the stability and performance is really sucky - and I fear that the company delivering the backend (BC ->AX) is doing something *really* wrong here...

Comment: Can you add more info?  Are you doing this from scratch or do you already have a webfront? is it B2B, B2C...  Are you planning to buy or build?

Comment: I've added more info now - and also, It's B2C...

Answer (score 0):

EP connects to AX data and logic throw the BC. So, if your application with BC performance is slower that EP can't be directly fault of the BC itself.

*(EP: AX Enterprise Portal, BC: AX .NET Bussiness Connector)*

Comment: Whoo - this is a dead corpse - but still thanks for a reply.

EP adds an extra layer on top of BC providing a custom "mutex" - thus overcomming the issue with multiple sessions stumbling on each other causing performance issues. This was the case here when BC was exposed "directly" to the end user via the DAL. 

What could have been done was using a singleton-pattern in the DAL to ensure only one instance of the BC used(or a certain amount of BC' depending on the license) in addition to a queing system controlling the flow of request sent in to the BC-pipe via DAL.

Comment: Also - the project ended for a while ago - and the end of the story here was that I implemented a custom database connector on top of Linq2Sql where a certain amount of business logic needed for data to come out correct was added. In addition a persistent caching was added in between the DAL and database connector. At the end we got a quite snappy solution which was custom made for this project.